# npm error " The header content contains invalid characters" when installing React-Native?

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

```
$ sudo npm install –g react-native-cli
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/bin/–g
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "–g"       "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! The header content contains invalid characters
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/bin/npm-debug.log
```

I am following the guide from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Hitting a wall with that error. I have XCode installed and can't find a solution to this next step.

Comment: Which version of XCode do you have installed?

Comment: 7.1 - XCode was just a step to start working with React Native.

Comment: Aright just asked cause the tutorial says you needed 7.0+ but you do

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Homebrew to uninstall node and reinstall the latest version. I made sure the latest version of npm was also installed.